# C++ Why it's not the same address (pointers)

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

i tested some new functions of c++14 and I wondered why these pointers do not have the same address

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Test
{
public  :
    Test(){std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;}
    Test(int val){value = val;}
    ~Test(){std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;}

private :
    unsigned int value;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::unique_ptr<Test> ptr(new Test(45));
    std::cout << &ptr << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<Test> ptr2 (std::move(ptr));
    std::cout << &ptr2 << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

```
Output : 
    0xffffcbb0
    0xffffcba0 //Why it's not the same as previous 
    Destructor
```

Thank you :) and have a good day

Comment: FWIW, this is C++11 code. There's nothing specific to C++14 in there.

Comment: You never move the address of variables. You move their values.

Answer (score 16):

You are printing out the addresses of the `unique_ptr` variables themselves, not the addresses that they point to. Use the [`unique_ptr::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) method instead of the `&` operator:

```
std::unique_ptr<Test> ptr(new Test(45));
std::cout << ptr.get() << std::endl;

std::unique_ptr<Test> ptr2 (std::move(ptr));
std::cout << ptr2.get() << std::endl;
```

Comment: thank you, but when i execute your code the address of ptr2 is 0 || ptr = 0x6000284d0 , 
ptr2 = 0

Comment: i think it's because of my compilator

Comment: @AdamBrevet: the second time you still use `ptr` instead of `ptr2`. `ptr` has been moved out so its value is expected to be 0.

Comment: Unlikely to be a compiler bug.

Comment: OK, excuse I, it's an error from me. It's works. Thank you for the answers